# Is there a PHP version of zxcvbn.js or a way that I can use it server side to enforce a password rule?

Tags: php, javascript, passwords, server-side, verify

I'm using zxcvbn, a password strength checker, to display the strength of a password.

I would like to enforce a certain level of strength using the provided algorithm, but obviously it can be tampered with on the client side so I also need to verify the password on the server side to make sure. As far as I can tell there is no PHP version of zxcvbn currently and I don't have time to port it right now.

What would my options be?

Comment: If someone goes out of their way to bypass your password strength checker, does that really matter to you?  Is this for some regulatory reason?

Comment: If users go out of their way to bypass this one rule then they should bear responsibility for the consequences. If it were up to me I wouldn't go any further than that, but it may not be up to me and I should have a plan B just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PHP port of a Python port of zxcvbn available on github at https://github.com/Dreyer/php-zxcvbn. Note, the author states that at this time it is not recommended for production use.

Comment: Since this comment I've developed a psr0 PHP lib based on zxcvbn https://github.com/bjeavons/zxcvbn-php